# Group_concat in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, group-concat, virtuoso

I am a beginner with SPARQL, and I am trying to deal with the endpoint of the [Spanish National Library](http://datos.bne.es/sparql).

I have a code that works, here it is:

```
prefix bne: <http://datos.bne.es/def/> # base URI for ontology documented at http://datos.bne.es/def/
prefix resource: <http://datos.bne.es/resource/> 
select distinct 
?book
?author
?title
?subtitle
?ISBN
?publisher
?date
?pags
?size
?series
?edition
?subjectLabel
where { 
?book a bne:C1003 .
?book bne:P3001 "Errata Naturae" .
?book bne:P1011 ?author .
?book bne:P3002 ?title .
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3013 ?ISBN }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3001 ?publisher }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3006 ?date }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3004 ?pags }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3007 ?size }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3016 ?series }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P1004 ?date }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3017 ?edition }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3014 ?subtitle }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:OP3008 ?subject }
?subject rdfs:label ?subjectLabel
}
limit 50
```

But as some books has two or more subjects, the SPARQL repeats them in the results. I used `group_concat`, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
prefix bne: <http://datos.bne.es/def/> # base URI for ontology documented at http://datos.bne.es/def/
prefix resource: <http://datos.bne.es/resource/> 
select distinct 
?book
?author
?title
?subtitle
?ISBN
?publisher
?date
?pags
?size
?series
?edition
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?subjectLabel); separator="//") as ?subjects)
where { 
?book a bne:C1003 .
?book bne:P3001 "Errata Naturae" .
?book bne:P1011 ?author .
?book bne:P3002 ?title .
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3013 ?ISBN }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3001 ?publisher }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3006 ?date }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3004 ?pags }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3007 ?size }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3016 ?series }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P1004 ?date }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3017 ?edition }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:P3014 ?subtitle }
OPTIONAL {  ?book bne:OP3008 ?subject }
?subject rdfs:label ?subjectLabel
}
limit 50
group by ?book
order by ?date
```

Does someone know where I am making a mistake?

Thanks!

Edit:

I was doing one thing wrong: as @AKSW said, I have to group all the variables at the end of the code, or add variables on the select. I have a reduced version of the code for testing this:

```
PREFIX  bne:  <http://datos.bne.es/def/>
PREFIX  resource: <http://datos.bne.es/resource/>

SELECT  ?book ?author ?title (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?subject ; separator='//') AS ?subjects)
WHERE
  { ?book  a                     bne:C1003 ;
           bne:P3001             "Errata Naturae" ;
           bne:P1011             ?author ;
           bne:P3002             ?title ;
           bne:OP3008            ?subject
  }
#group everything here
GROUP BY ?book ?author ?title
```

@JeenBroekstra, when I run it in a SPARQL Validator, it says it is OK, but when I try to run it in the [SPARQL endpoint](http://datos.bne.es/sparql) of the library, it gives me an error:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 6: syntax error at 'GROUP_CONCAT' before '('
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't produce it here"? The GROUP_CONCAT does not work?

Comment: It seems strange `group by ?books` when you haven't used a variable named `books` in the query...

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote «group by ?books» instead of «group by ?book». But that wasn't the mistake: the code above with the group_concat result in an error.

Comment: Of course it results in an error. You can't use aggregate functions without grouping, and here you have to i) group by all other variables as well or ii) use aggregate functions on the variables that have been selected, e.g. `SAMPLE`

Comment: So I imagine this example should work… But still persist the error:
`PREFIX  bne:  <http://datos.bne.es/def/>
PREFIX  resource: <http://datos.bne.es/resource/>
SELECT  ?book ?author ?title (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?subject ; separator='//') AS ?subjects)
WHERE
  { ?book  a                     bne:C1003 ;
           bne:P3001             "Errata Naturae" ;
           bne:P1011             ?author ;
           bne:P3002             ?title ;
           bne:OP3008            ?subject
  }
GROUP BY ?book ?author ?title`

Comment: @Nikita: what is the error message? Please [edit] your question to add this info.

Comment: @Nikita That is a pretty old version of the Virtuoso triple store as backend and dos **not** support SPARQL 1.1 . There is no workaround with SPARQL 1.0 except setting up a newer Virtuoso by the people hosting the endpoint.

Comment: Then the problem is with the endpoint… :(
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, the problem is that the [target endpoint](http://datos.bne.es/sparql) is running on [Virtuoso, Open Source Edition, v06.01.3127 as of 2011-11-16](http://datos.bne.es/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_dbms_name%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fname%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_dbms_ver%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fversion%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_thread_model%27%29%20AS%20%3Fthread%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_opsys_id%27%29%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fopsys%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_date%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fdate%20%29%0D%0A%23%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_lic_owner%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fowner%20%29%0D%0A%23%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_lic_serial_number%27%29%20%20AS%20%3Fserial%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)), which did not support `GROUP_CONCAT` in SPARQL, as SPARQL 1.1 had not yet been finalized.

Upgrading to a [current version](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews) is strongly recommended!

There is a built-in function in this version of Virtuoso, available as [`sql:group_concat`, as documented](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_group_concat/), which may serve you for now.